# How do you call a vector of length $n$, with all values equal to $\frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: terminology, vectors

Is there a specific name for a vector of dimension $n$, with all values equal to $\frac{1}{n}$?

So, a vector that looks like this:

$\vec{v} = \underbrace{(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})}_n$

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It's the average of all canonical unit vectors.

Comment: Why do you need specific name for a such vector?

Comment: I'm using it in my thesis, so it would be useful if I could refer to it by a specific name.

Comment: this is the "vector of all ones" $e=(1,1,...,1)$ (this vector is commonly referred as such) times 1/n.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just define $\overline{e} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n e_k$?